# Java Restaurant EPOS system - Landline telephone integration

Tags: java, telephony, epos

I've been trying to develop my own EPOS system for a takeaway and I want to include a telephone receiver feature.

Basically, when a customer calls on the landline number, the number should be shown on the java application. How do I go about doing that?

I had a look online and I found JTAPI but I don't really know how to implement it and whether it'll work with analog phones.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Edit: Just to add some more details: I currently just have a laptop and a regular  analog phone. Could I set something up with that alone, or would I need some more hardware?

Comment: Use asterisk. And then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38263374/how-to-get-the-phone-numbercallerid-in-asterisk

Comment: Thanks.I had a read about asterisk. It seems to me like asterisk is overkill for my needs or am I wrong?